# how to properly add material-ui to a project?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I try to add material-ui to my React project.

after running `npm install material-ui -S` I try to include an example from the documentation.

```
      <div>
        <RaisedButton onClick={this.handleTouchTap} label="Click me" />

        <Popover
          open={open}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom' }}
          targetOrigin={{ horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top' }}
          onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
        >
          <Menu>
            <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Help &amp; feedback" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Settings" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
          </Menu>
        </Popover>
      </div>
```

I import desired material-ui component in the following way
`import { RaisedButton, Popover, Menu, MenuItem } from 'material-ui';`

and this leads to an error with following stack trace.

[image]

Comment: Looks odd, I see the example in a different way. Look at this link for the raise button example https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/#flat-buttons it has a different implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the [usage](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage) in their docs?

You need to include a `import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';` at the top of your app.

Comment: no, I did not. didn't know about that. need to try this out

Answer (score 1):

I also have this same problem. I hope I can add to the answer submitted by *BravoZulu*.

You need to wrap your `material-ui code source snippet` with an element tag of `<MuiThemeProvider>` (like for example below):

```
<MuiThemeProvider>

    ...code source from material-ui 

</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.  :)